# Change Google Map marker color with external jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, marker

I'm using this function to draw the marker:

```
function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: 'M31.5,0C14.1,0,0,14,0,31.2C0,53.1,31.5,80,31.5,80S63,52.3,63,31.2C63,14,48.9,0,31.5,0z M31.5,52.3 c-11.8,0-21.4-9.5-21.4-21.2c0-11.7,9.6-21.2,21.4-21.2s21.4,9.5,21.4,21.2C52.9,42.8,43.3,52.3,31.5,52.3z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 0,
        scale: 1,
   };
}
```

and this is my marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: map.getCenter(),
icon: pinSymbol("#fff"), //defined marker color
labelText: 'HERE WE ARE',
labelVisible: true,
labelClass: "label",
labelZIndex: 99,
draggable: false,
map: map
});
```

I have a color pallete in other file with the jQuery script that changes a lot of colors on the page when user choose some color, but I don't know how to change color of this marker also.

Can I somehow change color of the marker externaly, in some other file?

Comment: Does the file that has a color picker have click events? Can you show it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a variable using var keyword in javascript that is a local variable. If you want to reach that variable from another javascript file, you need to pass this reference around  or use a global variable. 
With global variable approach, easiest to understand but in the long run hardest to maintain, you may do something like following:

CreateMap.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: 'M31.5,0C14.1,0,0,14,0,31.2C0,53.1,31.5,80,31.5,80S63,52.3,63,31.2C63,14,48.9,0,31.5,0z M31.5,52.3 c-11.8,0-21.4-9.5-21.4-21.2c0-11.7,9.6-21.2,21.4-21.2s21.4,9.5,21.4,21.2C52.9,42.8,43.3,52.3,31.5,52.3z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 0,
        scale: 1,
   };
}
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        icon: pinSymbol("#fff"), //defined marker color
        labelText: 'HERE WE ARE',
        labelVisible: true,
        labelClass: "label",
        labelZIndex: 99,
        draggable: false,
        map: map
    });

    // global variables set
    window.currentMap = map;
    window.mainMarker = marker;


  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

AnotherMapScript.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var marker = window.mainMarker;
    marker.setIcon(pinSymbol('#f20'));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without having a reference to your marker. As soon as you have that reference, it's easy:

`marker.setIcon(pinSymbol('#f00'));`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Comment: can you please help me to get reference to the marker or give me some example?

Comment: The marker reference is, from your code above, the variable `marker`. Are you storing these markers somewhere (in an array or an object) so you can access them later? Or are you just creating them and not doing anything with the `var marker` that is returned from `new google.maps.Marker({...})`?

Comment: I just create infoBox with:

`var ibLabel = new InfoBox(infowindow);
ibLabel.open(map,marker);`

Nothing else.